Kubernetes Ingress
How do I forward a request to the path (/auth/v1/validateToken) in service1 to validate when a request is made to the path (/user/v1/account/summary) in service2?
The request should be routed back to the path (/user/v1/account/summary) in service2 when HTTP_RESPONSE is 200 or validated; otherwise, an error code should be returned.
 - host: abc.com
   http:
     paths:
     - path: /auth/v1/validateToken
       pathType: Prefix
       backend:
         service:
           name: service1
           port:
             number: 80
    
     - path: /user/v1/account/summary
       pathType: Prefix
       backend:
         service:
           name: service2
           port:
             number: 80


This authentication logic is usually built as a middleware for all your routes in your application. K8s ingress is not the right place to solve this problem.

In Kubernetes, it's best to handle authentication directly within your application. If you need to manage complex traffic rules, tools like Istio can help, but they aren't typically used for authentication. Focus on adding the authentication checks in your app's code, and let Kubernetes handle routing the traffic
